The commandButton needs to be clicked twice to call the method
I am in the process of migrating an application with JSF pages to JBoss #7.4. Started experiencing couple of issues as given below. However, my application with the JSF pages works well with JBoss #6.1.

Was throwing an exception - This I could fix per this post  h:messages does not display messages when p:commandButton is pressed by disabling ajax call: "ajax = false".

Button needs to be clicked twice to call the method mentioned in an action attribute.


I have given below the code of xhtml & the calling java method. Can someone throw some light so that method will be called with a single click of the button?.
Thank you,
xhtml:
 <h:form id="ifgCreatorForm" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;">  
                        <p:growl id="eventGuideGrowl" for="eventBean" sticky="true"/>
                        <div class="eventBar">
                            <span style="display:inline-block; position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0px; text-align: center;">
                                <span class="eventLink eventLinkActive excludeKeepAlive">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{msg.ifg_label}"/>                                            
                                </span>
                                <p:commandLink id="navigateToJob" action="#{event.goToJob()}" styleClass="excludeKeepAlive" process="@this" update="eventGuideGrowl" >
                                    <span class="eventLink excludeKeepAlive">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.job_label}"/>
                                    </span>
                                </p:commandLink>
                                <p:commandLink id="navigateFromIfgToEvent" action="#{event.goToEvent()}" styleClass="excludeKeepAlive" process="@this" update="eventGuideGrowl" >                                            
                                    <span class="eventLink excludeKeepAlive">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{msg.event_label}"/>                                              
                                    </span>
                                </p:commandLink>    
                            </span>
                            <p:commandButton value="#{msg.next}" id="eventNextButton" action="#{event.goToJob()}" styleClass="eventGuideNext excludeKeepAlive" process="@this" update="eventGuideGrowl" />                                                        
                        </div>

Java Method:

@Named("event")
@ConversationScoped
public class EventBean implements Serializable {
  public String goToJob() {
    logger.info("In goToJob");
    return eventGuidePageNavigation.TO_JOB.toString();
    }

 public String goToEvent() {
    logger.info("In goToEvent");
    return eventGuidePageNavigation.TO_EVENT.toString();
    }
}

